# Can I set my HTC Desire into sync-mode without using touch screen

Tags: backup, htc-desire, touchscreen, broken-screen, htc-sync-3.0

The screen of my HTC Desire just broke (It's not shattered, but it's completely black).
I have no reason to believe anything else is broken (When I start it up, I hear the short tune that plays when the logo is normally displayed). Now, I'd really like not to lose any data, so I'd like to sync it to a PC using USB; however, I've set the default mode to tethering.

Is there any way for me to set the phone to sync-mode or any other way for me to recover my data?

I know that I can extract the memory card and use a card reader for that data. This question is specifically about the data that doesn't reside on the extractable memory card.

Answer (score 2):

If the device itself works as you suggest you might be able to access the recovery mode, enable USB and then download the files you need. However this will not be a USB sync access, instead it can be a fastboot or ADB access.

To do so take your Desire which have to powered off and press and hold <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>. Now start it up by pressing <kbd>Power</kbd>.

In the recovery mode you are able to enable USB access via ADB. As the recovery mode uses only <kbd>Volume Down</kbd>, <kbd>Volume Up</kbd> and <kbd>Power</kbd> it can be controlled even without seeing anything.

You only have to know which keys have to be pressed in which order. This is of course the complicated part. I don't have an unrooted device with the original recovery here for giving you the orders which keys to press. May be you find an Youtube video showing it or a very detailed manual.

Comment: This is very helpful information. I'll see what I can work out and report back with the result.