# Backup apps on SGS 2 with broken display?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, backup, broken-screen

the display of my Samsung Galaxy S2 got broken and I need to backup my apps. Is that possible without the phone's screen? There are no backup apps on the phone and it's not rooted. I don't know the exact OS version. Bought it 24 months ago.

After the crash I was able to connect the phone to Kies via USB and made a backup. Then I gave the phone to the repair shop of the accident insurance. But afterwards I read about that Kies won't backup your apps and as I still have one Bitcoin on the phone and also would like to restore other apps, I now think about getting it back from the repair shop, because if they repair it, all data will be gone.

So is there any way to get my apps back?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Do you have Developer options enabled?

Comment: See also: [Backup and restore CM10 on broken razr](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/36280/16575) / [Can I set my HTC Desire into sync-mode without using touch screen](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25453/16575) (not CM-dependent) / the [backup tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/backup/info) (also CM-independent ;))

Comment: no, developer options are not enabled.

Comment: Related: [How to perform a full system dump/backup with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54272/16575)

Answer (score 0):

**Requires CWM:**

from [codemink](http://codemink.com/backup-or-restore-android-through-adb/):

> **Backup Your Device**
>   Start the phone in recovery mode and make sure that it is recognized by the PC. Open a terminal in the folder where the executable adb (usually C: \ Program Files \ Android \ android-sdk \ platform-tools)  is located and execute the following commands:

```
adb backup -f boot.img boot
adb backup -f system.img system
adb backup -f data.img data
```

> **Restore Your Device**
>   With the phone in recovery mode, start the terminal with these commands as explained below:

```
 adb shell echo -n boot > /tmp/ro.bu.restore
 adb restore boot.img
 adb shell echo -n system > /tmp/ro.bu.restore
 adb restore system.img
 adb shell echo -n data > /tmp/ro.bu.restore
 adb restore data.img
```

Comment: The commands on the page you linked were formatted incorrectly, I replaced them from the [original source](https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/Dr5urg4XY8Q). Also, if I understood correctly, this requires ClockWorkMod Recovery to be installed.

Comment: Thank you for the edit, I just read that now, I didn't see that before. Thanks, will edit.

Comment: there is no CWM on my phone.. so does that mean it will not work for me?

Comment: I see you also do not have developer options enabled. If developer options were enabled you would have a lot easier time with this, can you get your device into recovery mode perhaps?

Comment: Never started it in recovery mode, but I think it should work. Please note that I don't have the phone here right now. It would take ~1 week to send it back here, so I want to be sure that I will be able to make a backup.