# Get phone data out when screen is dead

Tags: adb, screen

I have rooted Samsung Galaxy S2 with Rootbox Android 4.2.2 installed. My phone screen is dead and I want to get following data out of the phone.

- SMS (Most important)
- Photos
- Other files in internal card

Everything in the phone is working except the screen. I can call my phone and everything.

Whenever I try to connect to computer, it connects as MTP device and shows nothing inside it. Had there been a way to start the Airdroid or something to take the screenshot in realtime so that I can take backup of data and upload it on dropbox or google drive, it would have been easier.

I would like know if it is possible to access screenshot of my device through adb or something? If yes, which softwares and tools I will need to install? Are there any other methods that I can use to make it faster.

Comment: Have you checked [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575) and [Backup apps on SGS 2 with broken display?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/51629/16575)

Comment: Do you have adb debugging enabled? Is there a custom recovery & mod installed or do you run a rooted stock ROM? You can  probably get all back. Least you can do: buy or borrow another display.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I tried Droid@Screen application and connected to phone as mentioned on tutorial on their site. After that screen was visible on my computer and then trial and error touch events did rest of the things. Connected to computer now as usb device and copying the data. :)