# Samsung galaxy 4 smashed screen

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, broken-screen

i have a samsung galaxy 4 with a  smashed screen, i really need to get my contact numbers and calendar from it (currently using a friends old iphone but will be borrowing sisters old s4 soon. Phone charges and light flashes at top when turned on but unable to see anything due to the damage. Desperate for help please!!!

Comment: See: [How do I backup data (SMS/contacts) from a device with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/25646/16575) / [How to backup broken screen phone when USB debugging IS NOT enabled?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/67352/16575) / [How to perform a full system dump/backup with a broken screen?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54272/16575) and our [broken-screen tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have logged in your Gmail account on your galaxy 4. Your contacts & calendar are already backed up to Gmail server. You can easily get access to them by logging into your Gmail account through your PC and click on Gmail icon at top left of your screen -> select Contact. For calendar click on square tiles at top right of screen and select calendar.

You can get the contacts and Calendar details on your Iphone also by logging the same gmail account to your IPhone which you had used in your broken S4.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Windows or Mac box to connect it to? Samsung has http://www.samsung.com/us/kies/ which will let you grab the info off via a USB cable - screen only required if it has a lock on it.