# How do I recover data from a phone with a broken screen

Tags: backup, broken-screen, data-transfer

So, I broke my phone's screen recently, and it had a lot of important data.  I cannot see or use the screen, and I want to get all my data off the phone. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: besides you'll propably find a solution if you click on the tag, depending on phone model, android version and additional information like usb-settings, encryption, bootloader state you may get answer

Comment: Duplicate of [How to perform a full system dump/backup with a broken screen?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/54272/how-to-perform-a-full-system-dump-backup-with-a-broken-screen)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using my phone app, you can get some data.
Also, if your phone has already been rooting or debug enabled you can connect via adt.